# Error : Input string was not in a correct format." on eCommandArgument line C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added the error to this question's title.

I get an error with the below code.  Input string was not in a correct format.

The error happens on this line:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

How do I resolve this error?

The aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="MyMainPage" ContentPlaceHolderID="MMain" Runat="Server">
         <div id="awindow" >
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="main">
     <div style="width: 100%; float: left">    
         <asp:TextBox runat="server"  style="margin-left:5px; float:left;" ID="newauthor" />
         <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="addauthor" Height="17px" ToolTip="Add a new author"  ImageUrl="~/siteimages/Addbuttons/add.png" OnClick="AddAuthor_Click"/>
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAuthor" Text='<%# Bind("Author") %>' />
         <asp:Button ID="btnFindAuthor" runat="server" Text="Author Quick Find" CommandName="Select" OnCommand="btnFindAuthor_Click" />
         <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="authors" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="~/WebServices/authorsearchdisplay.asmx" ServiceMethod="AutoComplete" TargetControlID="authors" MinimumPrefixLength="3" />             
    </div>

    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sqlAuthors" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Libro %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Libro.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Authors" 
    InsertCommand="authors_GetOrCreate" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <InsertParameters>
             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="newAuthor" Name="authorame" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvAuthors" DataSourceID="sqlAuthors" DataKeyNames="AuthorID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
         <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Author Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/authors.aspx?id={0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="AuthorID" DataTextField="AuthorName" />
        </Columns>

     </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>

</div>

<div>

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

The script:

```
protected void btnFindAuthor_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select") 

    {
        // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
        // property to an Integer.
          int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString()); 


        // Get the last name of the selected author from the appropriate
        // cell in the GridView control.
        GridViewRow selectedRow = gvAuthors.Rows[index];

    }
}
```

Comment: And the error is...? *Always* give the details of any error you get.

Comment: My *guess* -- and this really is a guess because you didn't include the actual error -- is that you're getting a FormatException. Have you stepped through your code and examined what `e.CommandArgument.ToString()` is?

Comment: I would definitely use debugger ...

Comment: For the first time i saw @JonSkeet answered in the --**ordinary**-- people's page LOL

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx) to button.

Otherwise, `int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());` will throw exception.

For example -

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFindAuthor" runat="server" Text="Author Quick Find" 
    CommandName="Select" 
    OnCommand="btnFindAuthor_Click" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
```

Comment: I assigned the Bind"AuthorID" to the CommandArgument,ran the code and still got the same error.  Just to be safe, I also assigned it exactly as Win suggested and ran the code.  Still got the same error.  Really confused.  According to what I've read, if I bind the variable to the commandargument, whatever is selected from the autocompleteextender should be passed.

Comment: I do not understand why you need `CommandArgument` in first place. Unfortunately, I can only show you whether the error is; other than that I have no clue what the web page should function. My suggestion will be to set break points, and debug line-by-line.

Comment: Win- I set breakpoints and went line-by-line. The error still happened on the same line. What I select from the findauthors text box is not getting passed.  I found the commandargument in one of the tips here.  Do you know of a more efficient way to pass my variable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's an error when casting from string to int, try:

```
const int DefaultIndexValue = 1;

int index;
if (!Int32.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out index))
{
    index = DefaultIndexValue;
}
```

Comment: Tried adding the error. Hit enter button andit submitted my question before I could add the error. here is the error again:  {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

Comment: What does the error message say?  Can you add the line `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(e.CommandArgument.ToString());` and report what value it's showing?

Comment: ystem.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
       at ASP.authors_default_aspx.btnFindAuthor_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) in Authors\Default.aspx:line 18

Comment: at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: